# Variables in shell_exec() script

Tags: php, shell, variables

Is there any possible way to make this simple script function properly?

```
<?php
$hi = "echo hi";
shell_exec($hi);
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

please help me out?

Comment: shouldn't `shell_exec($hi);` read `$output = shell_exec($hi);`?

Comment: thx, i must have accidentally deleted something, thats what i had originally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure just assign the variable.

```
<?php
$hi = "echo hi";
$output = shell_exec($hi);
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$hi = "echo hi";
# the result needs to be assigned to $output before using it
$output = shell_exec($hi);
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```