# Why does the Php exec function, returns Array( )?

Tags: php, cmd, exec

I am working on a php script that tries to get the username of the person on a given computer on a server.

Here's the code im using
    `exec('wmic COMPUTERSYSTEM Get UserName', $user);

    print_r($user);`

And when ever this runs i always get back  `Array( )`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use exec to return any output from your command.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183703/store-php-exec-in-a-session-variable).But you can use [shell_exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800687/variables-in-shell-exec-script) to return the output of your command.

You can have an array of computer:

```
$computer = array('comp1', 'comp2');
$comp1 =  array();

foreach($computer as $username)
{
    $comp1 = shell_exec("wmic /node: ". $username ." computersystem Get UserName");
    print_r($comp1);
}
```

But if there is only one:

```
$user = shell_exec('wmic /node: <yourcomputername> COMPUTERSYSTEM Get UserName');
print_r($user);
```

But i suggest to get logged users, there is a tool from sysinternals that i used to do certain task like executing process remotely, list info about the system through command prompt.

Checkout and install [PSTools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx). Then you can use the PsLoggedon.exe

Comment: So how should i be printing this? should i just echo the shell_exec? or is there a certain way i should do it?

Comment: do you have an array of $user that you want to automate?

Comment: can you elaborate what you mean by automate?

Comment: are you going to run the command with one user only or you have a list of user stored in an array and want to get their usernames?

Comment: I have a list of different computers, and im checking to see if there is ANYONE logged onto it. and i believe only one person can be logged on at a time.

Comment: Sorry i just saw the edit, I am aware of PsLoggedon, however I do not have the capability to install PsLoggedon to the machines on my server(Its a school server, and i have admin privileges). I wanted to use `wmic` because then all i would need to do is put in the admin username and pass to get access to all the computers in the school.

Answer (score 0):

**exec** always return a array, if the output argument is present

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

If your code return only one user, try this:

```
$user = shell_exec('wmic COMPUTERSYSTEM Get UserName');
echo $user;
```

**shell_exec** manual:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

**It may be disabled if PHP is in safe mode.**

Look:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.functions.php

You can check your server's PHP settings with the phpinfo() function.

Comment: hmm when i tried it, i didnt get any output, ill keep trying :)

Comment: Should i put the full path for this command in the ()'s? if so what would that look like?

Comment: just checked and it says safe_mode is off.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the array this way: `print_r($user[1]);`

```
exec('wmic COMPUTERSYSTEM Get UserName', $user);
print_r($user[1]);
```